# "in as little time possible" vs "in as little time as possible"

Tags: sentence-construction

I am working on some ad copy. Should I say:

> This guide will get you up and running in as little time possible.

or

> This guide will get you up and running in as little time **as** possible.

And does it make a difference?

Comment: I think your copy seems a bit laboured. Do you need such formality given that you are using 'up and running'? 'The guide will get you up and running in no time'; 'The guide will get you up to speed in no time'; 'With this guide, you'll be up and running in no time'; etc

Comment: You could say "as quickly as possible" instead of "in as little time as possible."